# Adhesive babyproofing foam took out chunks of paint/wall at windowsill, how to repair?

Tags: repair, paint

hoping to get some help please.

I had to remove an adhesive strip of baby proofing foam because instead of sticking to the wall, it was just peeling off thick chunks of paint and the white layer underneath it.

[image]

[image]

What's the best approach to fix this?

I don't plan to put more baby proofing foam, but I need to keep it from shedding little bits onto the carpet of my kids playroom.

House was built in the early 2000s, no lead, and I do have a bucket of the same wall paint to use after repairing this. Can't do anything major because I am a renter.

I appreciate anyone's help!

ETA: I don't think I should just paint over it as-is, right? I'm worried if I do it's just going to peel off again eventually with it being so uneven underneath.

Answer (score 2):

You pulled off the drywall compound.

Any loose chips must be removed. Then both edges will have to be filled with new compound and allowed to dry. Re-texturing can be done with spray cans, but to make it blend well the texture should be extending all the way to the window and down the wall about a foot or so.  Then repaint when the texture is dry.

The process is as much an art as a skill.  You may need to call a drywall repair company or a handyman with drywall repair experience, to get a repair that is unnoticeable.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thank you!